# How to expand a shell variable read from a text file using ksh script

Tags: shell, scripting

I am hoping if someone can show me how I can expand a variable ($ORACLE_PATCH_DIR) that is read from a file.

The code is as follows.

Input File:

```
cat patch_list_db.txt
$ORACLE_PATCH_DIR/32579100/32518631/31704029
```

Korn Shell Script

```
# Read one patch location at a time from the patch_list_db.txt file and apply the patch
while read DIR_NAME
do
  str="DIR_NAME: $DIR_NAME"
  print_function "$str"

  cd $DIR_NAME
  ls

  str="Current Dir: `pwd`"
  print_function "$str"

done <"$file_name"
```

Results:

```
./apply_db_patch.ksh patch_list_db.txt
Oracle Patch Dir:  /u2/patches
16:14:34 ===> DIR_NAME: $ORACLE_PATCH_DIR/32579100/32518631/31704029
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your `print_function` and other relevant parts, Try `echo "${!DIR_NAME}"`

Comment: The complete code is as follows.

Comment: print_function()
{
    date_str=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
    print_str=$date_str" ===> "$1
    echo $print_str
}